# Unable to send Post Request with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, api

I´m tring to make a post request, according the code below:

```
String url = new StringBuilder().append("https://...").toString();
Map<String, Map<String, String>> body = buildBotBody(email,message);
restTemplate.postForEntity(url, body, Void.class);
```

This request don´t needs authentication, it don´t needs login and password. At the Postman I can make the request with success, but when I try to execute the code above, I got:

401 Unauthorized

I got simulate the error at the Postman and it gave me the message below:

```
 "message": "The request has both SAS authentication scheme and 'Basic' authorization scheme. Only one scheme should be used."
```

When I changed the authentication method to "No Auth" at Postman, the request worked fine.

I think I have to set this option "No Auth" at the code, but I don´t know how.

I made this way:

```
private HttpEntity<?> builderHeadersToBuildBotBody(String email, StringBuilder message) {
    
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("emailadress", email);
    map.put("emailSubject", "Pendência para lançamento de horas do Jira");
    map.put("emailBody", message.toString());
    
    return builderHeaders(map);
}

private HttpEntity<?> builderHeaders(Map<String, String> map) {
    
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    //requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("application", "json")));
    requestHeaders.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "json"));
    //requestHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "");
    return new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders);
}

private void sendBotMessage(StringBuilder message, String nome, String email) throws Exception{
    
    try {
        String url = new StringBuilder().append("https://prod-12.westeurope.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/fbf4c29cbcad4679b1a1159fff7b07f9/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=zxm46aQnBj3ZTKPOddnnwUgtQZoQcQfixNtXVxAJjPg").toString();
        HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = builderHeadersToBuildBotBody(email,message);
        restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Void.class);
        logger.info("Bot enviado com sucesso! " + nome);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Erro ao enviar Bot.", e);
        throw e;
    }
    
}
```

But the error continues.

Comment: Endpoint is using https ?

Comment: Yes, I´m using https.

Comment: Seems very odd that Postman would not need auth ... while the RestTemplate would ... are there headers etc in the Postman request that aren't being represented in the java call ?

Comment: The code of cURL is this:

curl --location --request POST 'https://prod-12.westeurope.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/fbf4c29cbcad4679b1a1159fff7b07f9/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=zxm46aQnBj3ZTKPOddnnwUgtQZoQcQfixNtXVxAJjPg' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "emailadress": "bnascimentos@indracompany.com",
    "emailSubject": "Testando bot",
    "emailBody": "Se você visualizar esta mensagem o bot funcionou"
}'

Comment: I see. So the endpoint is on the cloud. And when you hit from postman running locally it works. When you run the restTemplate call that is failing, is that also running locally or on the cloud ?

Comment: The restTemplate is running locally too.

Answer (score 0):

If Spring Security is on your classpath you may need to disable authentication. This is done by creating a @Configuration class which extends the WebSecurityConfigurerAdaptor

```
@Configuration
public class NoSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Obviously this is something you would not want to do in production but can be useful in dev environments.

Comment: I´m not using Spring Security. Is there another way?

Comment: Can you provide your pom.xml (Assuming you're using maven)

Comment: It is too big to post here

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>br.com.oss.jira.quality</groupId>
<artifactId>jira-quality</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>jira-quality</name>
<description>Gerenciador de inconsistências no Jira</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.6</lombok.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0.1</version>
    </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>  -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <!-- Exclude the default Jackson dependency -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>${gson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>desenv</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>desenv</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>prod</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint requires authorization and you should provide it with the request (credentials, token, etc.). Clean the cookies on Postman and I guess it’ll stop working too.